# Do I need an access token for my web api service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, owin

I have an application for managing user data. All the business logic is encapsulated within a separate web api service, which the user management web application (among others) calls into. At the moment all web api calls are exposed (they are anonymous). However the web api sits on a separate domain and is only accessible to the applications that call into it.

Is there any benefit to adding bearer tokens and enforce authentication for each API call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the web api service is on a separate domain and adequately protected from the internet, then you dont need to authenticate at the service level for external security (over and above any application logins you have).

**However**, that is not to say that your application is not internally exposed and could be intentionally or accidentally called by malicious intent or an incorrectly configured application, for example, someone accidentally points a load test at production. For this reason I would secure it, [at least with a HMAC](http://bitoftech.net/2014/12/15/secure-asp-net-web-api-using-api-key-authentication-hmac-authentication/) if you dont want to implement full blown authentication.

EDITED: To add that with any public facing web real estate you should classify your data and decide the appropriate level of security to apply. In some circumstances you may not want to secure GETs of low sensitivity data. On the flip side, exposing GETs allows someone access to try denial of service attacks (by calling your API in a loop from multiple servers / a botnet). When it comes to POSTs, the risk is higher, since consumers will be inserting in to your datastore.

It's also always good to keep the [OWASP Top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10) in mind when dealing with security.

Comment: Good answer, I have checked out the link. It would be good to get more people to give their opinions on this matter. The core problem is that adding the token functionality would require some immense changes to a legacy system.

Comment: It's a question of balancing risk. I build payment systems so I am very security conscious. If your app is not very sensitive and could deal with being compromised, and you can afford to lose the downtime and restore from a backup, then maybe you can get away without modification and just accept the risk.